# Tang stops When Entering to another activity for scanning QR Code

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv, opengl-es, google-project-tango

I'm developing an application which is a google Tango project when I start another activity for scanning QR Code Tango stops and below error is displayed in logcat:-

```
11-20 10:31:17.247 548-13246/? E/Camera3-Device: RequestThread: Can't get output buffer, skipping request: Broken pipe (-32)
11-20 10:31:17.247 548-13246/? E/Camera3-OutputStream: getBufferLocked: Stream 0: Can't dequeue next output buffer: Broken pipe (-32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling  mTango.disconnect();(mTango is the object of Tango class)before transitioning out of a scene will prevent the crash. Thanks!